CPOL setting in STM32 SPI register causes weird pulse in waveform
I am using STM32H75. We have noticed an extra pulse/spike being generated, on the clock line(refer waveform), after the transmission of each word size. I am specifically saying CPOL because this problem doesn't persist when CPOL is 0 and is not triggered by CPHA.
What could be possible reasons for such behaviour?
CPOL 1 and CPHA 1 
CPOL 0 and CPHA 1 
Here I am probing the CLK line. if you see I am getting an extra spike after the 8 clock pulses when CPOL is 1
Expecting no extra spikes
Transmission code:
template<typename T>
bool HardSPI::spiWrite(T data)
{
  _spi->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART;
  *((T *)&_spi->TXDR) = data;
  while (!_isTXFIFOEmpty())
    ;
  return true;
}

Above the driver function to write SPI TX register. the blocking delay has been added to avoic collisions on the SPI bus while transmitting multiple words continuously

spike [...] after the transmission of each word size - Show code which does that transmission (add it using edit to the initial post)

Are your GPIO configured correctly? Your waveform looks a little fuzzy, it can sometimes happen if you use a GPIO with peripheral while not having it properly configured for alternate function. If it's weakly driven, it can cause additional spikes. As noted in the previous comment, the code would be welcome.

hey, I have attached the driver code for transmission

So the reason behind the spike was because the GPIO was configured to high speed on the GPIO registers(refer to STM TRM for more information). Removing that line of code, seemed to solve the problem.
